# Error 404: Prob accessing /solr/update. Reason: Not Found

Tags: xml, solr, lucene

I've followed the [solr tutorial](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_9_0/tutorial.html) and renamed the default collection1 to core1, but when I'm getting error 404 trying to import a XML to solr using the following  command:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/update --data-binary @monitor.xml -H 'Content-type:application/xml'
```

Here is the response:

```
<h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you rename the collection to core1 you should be running this command:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/core1/update --data-binary @monitor.xml -H 'Content-type:application/xml'
```

That is, you add the collection name in between "solr" and the action - same thing applies for queries:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/select?q=solr&wt=xml
```

Comment: Glad to help, if you found the answer useful and addressed your issue kindly accept the answer.

Comment: @JohnPetrone, I am getting similar error. I am trying from last 2days. I posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838233/solr-issue-accessing-solr-categories-categories-update#  -- Need your help please.

Answer (score 3):

I was working with SolrNet and I get the same error. 
What I did was:

- Run Solr with products:  `$solr-5.5.0\bin>solr start -e techproducts`
- Change SolrNet Sample App

  - **web.config** `SolrUrl` from `http://localhost:8983/solr` to `http://localhost:8983/solr/techproducts`
  - **Global.asax.cs** comment out the call to the method `AddInitialDocuments()`
- Run the SolrNet Sample App