# HTTP ERROR 404 while accessing solr admin

Tags: java, solr, lucene, solrj

I am using `solr-6.5.1`. I was able to install Solr, create a collection, index files using my application and also search for data from Solr. I was using the following URL to access Solr: `http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm` Everything was working fine for me until today. Now when I try to access the above URL, it gives the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /solr/swcm. Reason:

    Not Found
```

But if I use the following URL: `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/swcm` I am able to access the Solr admin. But the issue with this url is when I try to search for data in the collection using my `Spring MVC Java` application. I get the following exception:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/smartwcm-admin] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/swcm: Expected mime type application/xml but got text/html. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

And the code I use is:

```
solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/#/swcm").build();
solrClient.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setQuery("pageTitle:"+searchKey+"*);
query.setFields("webContentDefinitionId");
query.setStart(start);   
query.setRows(count);
query.set("defType", "edismax");
QueryResponse response = null;;
response = solrClient.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docList = response.getResults();
```

I am not sure what went wrong all of a sudden.

Comment: try taking the # out of the URL

Comment: @browskie, "http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm" is giving me an http 404 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `#` into your base url `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/swcm`.

Try removing the misleading character:

```
solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm").build();
```

I also suppose `swcm` is the name of your core/collection.

But you can't use `http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm` directly into your browser, because this is the baseurl for all the requests.

For example you can try with `http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm/select?q=*:*&rows=10` which returns the first 10 documents in the `swcm` collection.

To understand better how is composed a Solr url, I'll split the given example in the main parts:

- Solr Url: `http://localhost:8983/solr/`
- [Core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Glossary#SolrGlossary-Core) or [Collection](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Glossary#SolrGlossary-Collection) name: `swcm`
- [Solr Request handler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig): `select`
- [Solr Query](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Standard+Query+Parser): `q=*:*&rows=10`

We can further break up the Solr Query in different parts:

- In `q=*:*`, which is a common query used for return all the documents, `q` is the Query parameter, the former `*` means any available field name and the latter `*` stands for any value. `q` defines a query using standard query syntax. This parameter is mandatory.
- `rows=10` simply means returns 10 documents.

Comment: @GeoThomas Given that I suppose `swcm` is the name of your core/collection, `http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm` is the baseurl for all the requests. You can't use it into the browser, but you can try with `http://localhost:8983/solr/swcm/select?q=*:*`.

Comment: @GeoThomas I've updated my answer giving a better description of how is composed and structured a Solr url

Answer (score 0):

One reason for this issue could be you haven't updated if you have changed the core name. 
Please see [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24654957/error-404-prob-accessing-solr-update-reason-not-found/24665731)

Also can you let me know what do you get when you access /solr/swcm/select?q=*

Answer (score 0):

Use solr base URL and add set collection to `swcm` using query.set("collection", swcm);

ex:

```
solrClient = new HttpSolrClient.Builder("http://localhost:8983/solr").build();
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("collection", swcm);
query.setQuery("pageTitle:"+searchKey+"*);
query.setFields("webContentDefinitionId");
query.setStart(start);   
query.setRows(count);
query.set("defType", "edismax");
QueryResponse response = null;;
response = solrClient.query(query);
SolrDocumentList docList = response.getResults();
```