# Spring Data Solr: HTTP ERROR 404 when updating Document

Tags: spring, solr, spring-data, solrj, solrcloud

I am doing a simple Search exercise in solr. I followed this tutorial. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-solr

I did all same. I run the test case I am getting an error like this:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/categories/categories/update. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
; nested exception is org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/categories: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
```

I am not able to understand why it taking **/solr/categories/categories/update** two times categories. My Categories class look like this:

My configurations:
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-webapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <relativePath /> lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.8</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-solr</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>


@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Indexed(name = "id", type = "string")
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name = "category", type = "string")
    private String category;

    @Indexed(name = "category", type = "string")
    private String categoryId;
    @Indexed(name = "divId", type = "string")
    private String divId;
}
```

My Application.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({ SolrConfig.class})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.myproject.webapi.solr.repository", namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:solr-named-queries.properties", multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrConfig {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

My SolrConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages = "com.myproject.webapi.solr.repository", namedQueriesLocation = "classpath:solr-named-queries.properties", multicoreSupport = true)
public class SolrConfig {

    @Bean
    public SolrClient solrClient() {
        return new HttpSolrClient("http://localhost:8983/solr");
    }

    @Bean
    public SolrTemplate solrTemplate(SolrClient client) throws Exception {
        return new SolrTemplate(client);
    }
}
```

My Repository class:

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Category, String> {

    public List<Category> findByCategoryId(String categoryId);
    public List<Category> findByCategory(String category);

    @Query("id:*?0* OR name:*?0*")
    public Page<Category> findByCustomQuery(String searchTerm, Pageable pageable);

    @Query(name = "Category.findByNamedQuery")
    public Page<Category> findByNamedQuery(String searchTerm, Pageable pageable);

}
```

My Unit Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SolrConfig.class)
public class CategoryRepositoryIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Before
    public void clearSolrData() {
        categoryRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void whenSavingCategory_thenAvailableOnRetrieval() throws Exception {
        final Category category = new Category();
        category.setId("P000089998");
        category.setCategory("OLD_COMS_FOOD");
        category.setCategoryId("9989999");
        category.setDivId("75");     

        categoryRepository.save(category);
        final Category retrievedCategory = categoryRepository.findOne(category.getId());
        assertEquals(category.getId(), retrievedCategory.getId());
    }
```

Comment: Please post the code to create your HttpSolrClient

Comment: I added now kindly see please.

Comment: Still not enough. Try adding the repository part, basically the rest.

Comment: I added repository kindly see please.

Comment: Find all references you have to `categories` - somewhere where it shouldn't be included it has been added - usually in the URL used to point to the core

Comment: It seems u must mention a core name at the end of the url. http://localhost:8983/solr/<core-name/ check out this link http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Expected-mime-type-application-octet-stream-but-got-text-html-td4358892.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if it causes the error: Category.category and Category.categoryId are both annotated to be named "category".

```
@Indexed(name = "category", type = "string")
private String category;

@Indexed(name = "category", type = "string")
private String categoryId;
```